# Ways to add LangVersion element into the .csproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I noticed that one of my projects was building in debug mode, but not release mode.

It turns out that the 'debug' profile had `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` defined in the `.csproj`, and was using some C#8 features, whereas it was absent from the 'release' profile.

This value was certainly not added by hand, by anyone in the team, so I'm wondering how else it could've made it into the `.csproj`? I don't believe there is a setting, nor will it be added by intellisense code suggestions.

[image]

Comment: IIRC, it can be added by Intellisense, when you try to write code that won't compile because of a feature that is known to work in newer versions of C#

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've just taken a screenschot - maybe it *did* offer it, but doesnt anymore.

Comment: I remember seeing it once or twice over the past 4-5 years, so it might be that only certain versions of Visual Studio offered it. Sorry I cannot be more specific than that

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show a project file. Intellisense won't show any CSPROJ tags in a C# file. As for the version, are you using VS 2017 perhaps? In the [language version defaults section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults) there's a note about this: `Visual Studio 2017 added a <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> entry to any project files it created. That meant C# 7.0 when it was added. However, once you upgrade to Visual Studio 2019, that means the latest released version, regardless of the target framework.`

Comment: And then `These projects now override the default behavior. You should edit the project file and remove that node. Then, your project will use the compiler version recommended for your target framework.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The thing is, I actually want to keep it - why would I want to be restricted to a lower language version? The only issue I can see would be compatibility with external build services or other developers.

Comment: @maxp it won't be restricted. The linked docs explain that the language version matches the runtime, so targeting NET 6 gets you C# 10, .NET 5 uses C# 9 etc. Targeting a preview SDK defaults to `preview`. You can't use a language version newer than the one supported by the SDK without tweaking anyway.

Comment: @maxp which means, you actually get restricted if you use `latest` to the latest stable version even if you target a preview SDK. For example, before the .NET 6 RCs if you used `latest` you'd get C# 9 instead of C# 10

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is a very good reason to "restrict" the version at compile time though, namely compatibility with older frameworks and Visual Studio versions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I take it there is no dependency for the 'client' executing a binary to the c# language? I.e. a user with only .NET 4.7.2 can still execute code compiled against the same framework but authored using a `LangVersion` of 10 (for example).